# Should I choose my hosting company's mail server, or make my own mail server on my Cloud server? (for security)

Tags: linux, security, email

I have a commercial website on an Ubuntu web server and my hosting company has a mail server for all its customers.

For security reasons, do you think I should rely on my hosting company's centralized mail server for my domain's email? Or should I just set up my own mail server on the same Cloud server?

Maybe I should use Google Apps' mail server for my own domain?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What security reasons would you be speaking of?

Comment: Hi, trying to turn off as many services as I can on my web server, turning off mail server to reduce the attack surface for example.

Comment: What do you think Google Apps is? Its still a shared email service. This is a shopping question and thus, not really suitable for SF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're going to be administering your mail setup on a regular basis, and want to care about anti spam measures, as well as additional attack surface for your server (as well as additional impact if it is down for whatever reason) I would either let the company host my mail, or use Google.

I personally use Google for my mail hosting, after having done it myself on my own server for many years.  IMHO It's just not worth the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is not to use shared mail servers that your hosting service is offering.

I recommend you to go thry Google Apps or if you want make your own .